# Loading CSS and JS using HTTPS on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, https

I'm trying to force HTTPS on a wordpress site, but my styles and scripts don't loading.

When I display page source code with Chrome I can see styles and scripts use HTTP to loading, I don't understand why.

I set HTTPS in wordpress general/settings for website URL and  for wordpress URL. It's a fresh wordpress install with a default theme.

I tried to add this in wp-config.php

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

It works but when I want to login to https://www.mywebsite.com/wp-admin, wordpress display me this message:

"Sorry you are not allowed to access this page"

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Have you done a replace on the database which replaces all old http urls to https? You use a seperate tool for this. Place the directory in the folder where you have your wp-config.php and it should connect automaticly to your database. Make a backup beforehand;

https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Comment: It's a fresh wordpress install with a default theme, I think there are only  website URL and for wordpress URL to change isn't?

Comment: @Rubyx probably yes, but the tool works for fresh installs too.